# Regex Javascript remove char after 'something'

Tags: javascript, regex

I had a sentence like this 'someurl.com/?something=1,2,3' i want to check if the char had `something=` then remove all character after that.

so like this.

```
'soome.url/?something=1,2,3,1' => 'soome.url/?'

'soome.url/nothing?nothingtoo?something=1,2,3,1' => 'soome.url/nothing?nothingtoo?'

'soome.url/nothing?something=1,2,3,1' => 'soome.url/nothing?'
```

how to do that in Javascript?

Comment: You know that URI query params are constructed using `&` as delimiter, do you, and that a query param does not necessarily need to be in the last position.

Comment: Yea but in my case I'll made that in last position always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already other pretty good answers with split method.

If you still want to know how to do it with regex

```js
let arr = [`soome.url/?something=1,2,3,1'`
,`soome.url/nothing?nothingtoo?something=1,2,3,1`,
`soome.url/nothing?something=1,2,3,1`]

arr.forEach(e=>{
  console.log(e.replace(/\?(?:something=.*)$/g,'?'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` and getting the first index will return the string before `something=`.

```js
const urlOne = 'soome.url/?something=1,2,3,1' // 'soome.url/?'
const urlTwo = 'soome.url/nothing?nothingtoo?something=1,2,3,1' // 'soome.url/nothing?nothingtoo?'
const urlThree = 'soome.url/nothing?something=1,2,3,1' // 'soome.url/nothing?'

function strip(url){
 return url.split('something=')[0];
}
console.log(strip(urlOne));
console.log(strip(urlTwo));
console.log(strip(urlThree));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's always the last parameter, you could just `split` the url at `something`:

```js
const url = 'soome.url/nothing?nothingtoo?something=1,2,3,1';
const newUrl = url.split("something")[0]
console.log(newUrl)
```

Comment: You forgot, as well as OP, that a query parameter does not necessarily need to be in the *last* position of an URI. And OP I think wants to remove only the associated value (for any unknown reason...)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you're right. I mentioned that assumption in the answer considering OP's all 3 examples showed them that way. Would've to use `URLSearchParams` if there is a possibility of any other position. But, I'm not even sure if `nothing?nothingtoo?something=1,2,3,1` is valid. IIRC, `URLSearchParams` splits based on `&` in the query string

Comment: Actually in my case its always in last one so... Yeah. @Roko

Comment: Well, in such case... yeah

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like following using `substr`.

```js
let url1 = "soome.url/nothing?nothingtoo?something=1,2,3,1";
let pattern = "something=";
let str2 = url1.substr(0, url1.indexOf(pattern) <= 0 ? str1.length : url1.indexOf(pattern));
console.log(str2);
```